# TClientDataSet and limit by memory

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

We have a system that creates reports out of our data.  And we can deal with *a lot* of data.  The idea of over 150,000 rows is not out of the question.

Unfortunately, our experience with `TClientDataSet` is its limitations, because it often results in an 'insufficient memory for this operation' error, when the data gets too big.

So the question is this: Does there exist a generally available implementation of `TDataSet` that can handle a large amount of data (such as streaming directly to a file and not keeping the entire dataset in memory)?

I am willing to implement such a class myself.  But as far as I understand `TClientDataSet`, it needs to be able to contain the data itself before it can save it to a file/stream.  In addition, loading the data again should also be possible as a stream rather than loading in an entire `TClientDataSet` object, because then we wouldn't have solved the issue.

Comment: I have not used them myself but I have read of using memory mapped files to do this with large amounts of data. You will probably have to roll your own dataset/methods that uses the files.

Comment: @Despatcher: Yeah, that is what we are doing now.  And it's going well.

Answer (score 4):

You can use either FireBird or Interbase in [embedded mode](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/fbmetasecur-embedded.html).

Comment: Although, I am a bit baffled how I actually get to use it *in* Delphi.  I cannot find a guide or an example of how to use Firebird/Interbase in embedded mode in Delphi.

Comment: @Svip Never done it myself, but I'd imagine it's the same (from Delphi's perspective) as non-embedded mode. Just drop the embedded server .dlls next to your .exe, and connect to them with a [Delphi library](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq8/).

Comment: The only difference is the connection string. You don't specify the server IP (because there isn't one). So if your database called MyDB.FDB is in a folder called C:\Data your connection string would be simply 'C:\Data\MyDB.FDB'. If you later decide to put the DB on a server, you can just change the connection string to suit. 

If you use embedded mode, you should be aware that it's strictly single-user only. Only one process can access the database at once.

Answer (score 1):

Is there really any need to cache all the data on the client before reporting?  If not, maybe rethink how you're querying and processing data to generate these reports and see if there's a way that involves less client-side data (which comes with a bonus of less data transmitted over the network).

If you've been down that road before and you really do need all this data client side, then you could look at custom data structures.  A `TList<T>` of records (even if you need to build your own indexes) takes a lot less memory than a `TClientDataSet` does.

Comment: Well.  It's technically not client side, as this is a server/service.  But I know what you mean.  However, the idea is to gather the data and place them into files, so when exporting them into visual formats, we don't have to collect the data every time.  So even if we resolve it for saving the data into files straight away, there will also be the problem of having to reopen the files.

Answer (score 0):

KBMMemTable is a nice alternative to TClientDataset

http://www.components4programmers.com/products/kbmmemtable/

We are using it for years and it is very useful and fast.

Comment: Still have memory size limits to think of.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to underline that the capacities of the TClientDataset could be something bigger.

Test on the limits of TClientDataset - appending xxx,xxx records, putting the single record in whole (repeated) to create an idea on the size.

// Begin Load Record to TCLientDataset for Reverse (on Reverse) Processing

dxMemData1.Append;

dxMemData1['NT_Rec_No']     := 1000;

dxMemData1['NT_User']       := 'DEV\Administrator';

dxMemData1['NT_Type']       := 'Information';

dxMemData1['Ora_Timestamp'] := '20170706033859.000';

dxMemData1['Ora_Host']      := 'DEV0001';

dxMemData1['Ora_SID']       := 'Oracle.orcl';

dxMemData1['Ora_Event_Id']  := '34';

dxMemData1['NT_Message']    := Memo1.Text;

dxMemData1.Post;

// End Load Record to TCLientDataset for Reverse (on Reverse) Processing

String on the memo1 is a of 100 characters - ansi

did several tests and managed to keep going to something from 600,000 to 900,000 records without crashing.

Difference can be made by making the text on the memo bigger - this did decrease the max number before crash - which means it is not a matter of exact max. record number - but of size consumed - my guess.

Tested the same with TdxMemData (devexpress), this time I could reach almost the double of records

Comment: if you are going this route for an answer to this question make it clear what you are doing. For example, what is `memo1`? What fields? How many records exactly? Every time the same number of records? How are you populating the ClientDataSet? Reading from a file? 32Bit or 64Bit?  Your findings that there is a third-party component _potentially consuming less_  memory were only added as an update, but this is what the question was looking for, so  put more emphasize on that?